# Is there a way through the vine blocked entrance in River Pass?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

So on my way through the River Pass there was a rock with markings that told me I could lift it. However, when I went to lift it the game told me to continue my path towards the mountain. After unlocking the fast travel system I came back and tried to do it again but was met with what looks like Freya’s vines.

I’m not sure how to get past them, does anyone know? This rock is near Brok’s shop in the river pass. It is beneath the bridge past where you find one of the artefacts for the area.

Comment: Could we get a screenshot? Just wanna make sure we know exactly what you're talking about

Comment: It won’t let me upload a picture, however, if you start at Brok’s shop in the river pass, go across the bridge and make a left, you will see a chain to drop down. It’s directly in front of the mystic gate, it will be at the very end of the path once you drop down the chain. There will be a body with an artifact lying next to him. If you continue you can lift yourself up to a higher path with a rock that is covered in the green vines (most likely made by the witch). When I fiat came to the river pass it was not blocked, but the game wouldn’t let me progress that way at all.

Comment: You should be able to edit the picture into your original post. I'll try and follow your instructions when I get home either way though.

Comment: It says my picture is too big and I can't find any pictures of the area on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

From memory you can't ever remove the vines or get back that way from the River Pass area.

Later in the game you do gain the ability to remove certain vines that are blocking your path or concealing a chests but it doesn't work on the vines in question. (Removable vines have a reddish colour.)

Again from memory, you can get to the other side of he blocked area by travelling to the Wild Woods and following the path you took originally. You will eventually come to a dead end at the ruined village, I think this is how you get to the area at the other side of the vines.

Will try and check this out later to confirm.

Comment: It's called Hel's Bramble, and they're blue in colour. Freya's Vines are green, and are permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a teaser for an update on that location. The rock has the markings as if you could interact with it but the vines cover it

Comment: Nevermind it’s the location right before the bridge breaks towards the beginning of the game